# Show section number in header if new section starts midway on that page, except when section starts on top of the page

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage

I am writing my thesis in the `oneside` `scrbook` class and would like the section number and name to show up on the top left of all pages (except pages on which a new chapter starts). I was facing the problem that if a new section starts halfway in the page, then the new section number and title would show up, whereas I wanted to show the section number and title that is on top of the page. The following code that I found on the internet *almost* fixed this:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[headsepline=true,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\makeatletter
\def\leftmark{\expandafter\@leftmark\topmark\@empty\@empty}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markleft{\textcolor{black}{\thesection}\ ~ #1}}
\clearpairofpagestyles % clear default page style
\lohead{~\leftmark} % section name and number on top left

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-8]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-1]
\section{Third section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

However, in the situation that a new section starts on the top of a page, the header still shows the previous section's number and title. What would be the easiest way to adjust the code above to keep the same functionality, but ensure that when a new section starts at the top of a page, the header shows *that* section's number and title?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\leftfirstmark` and remove your redefinition of `\leftmark`. However, with the shown example, I just would use `\automark[section]{section}`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[headsepline=true,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}% You should use \usepackage to load packages in documents.
\automark[section]{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles % clear default page style
\ihead{\headmark} % head mark as defined using \automark in the page head    
%\ofoot*{\pagemark}% Maybe adding pagination would be a good idea?

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-8]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-1]
\section{Third section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image: page 2 and 3 with the expected header]

There are other commands, described in the KOMA-Script manual, like: `\lefttopmark`, `\leftfirstmark`, `\leftbotmark`. If you, e.g., would use `\lefttopmark`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[headsepline=true,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}% You should use \usepackage to load packages in documents.
\automark[section]{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles % clear default page style
\ihead{\lefttopmark} % See the KOMA-Script manual for the meaning of \lefttopmark.    
%\ofoot*{\pagemark}% Maybe adding pagination would be a good idea?

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-8]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-1]
\section{Third section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

you'd get:

[image: using \lefttopmark]

So there are no marks, that result in: Getting the last mark of the previous page unless the section would start at the very beginning. So you would extra code to handle such cases, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[headsepline=true,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}% You should use \usepackage to load packages in documents.
\automark[section]{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles % clear default page style
\ihead{\lefttopmark} % See the KOMA-Script manual for the meaning of \lefttopmark.    
% \ofoot*{\pagemark}% Maybe adding pagination would be a good idea?
\newpairofpagestyles{sectionpagestyle}{\ihead{\leftfirstmark}}

\makeatletter
\AddtoDoHook{heading/postinit/section}{%
  \ifdim \dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax<3\baselineskip
    \pagebreak[4]%
    \thispagestyle{sectionpagestyle}%
    \typeout{Do it!}%
  \else
    \typeout{\the\pagegoal, \the\pagetotal, \the\baselineskip}%
  \fi
  \@gobble
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-8]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-1]
\section{Third section}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{Fourth section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: with extra code to detect, that the section will be at the page start]

But note: Such code can fail, e.g., if a section head would be followed by a large not breakable box.

BTW: If you want extra space between section number and section title in the heading, don't redefine `\sectionmark` but `\sectionmarkformat`, e.g.

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{\thesection\autodot\hspace{1.5em}}
```

See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about `\automark`, `\leftfirstmark`, `\headmark` and `\sectionmarkformat`. And for more information about page styles with KOMA-Script see, e.g., [“How change the head and foot of the page” in the KOMA-Script Wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_PageHeadFoot/) also [available in German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_PageHeadFoot/).

Off-topic: In the example I would suggest to use `scrreprt` (without option) instead of `scrbook` with option `oneside`, but maybe there is a not shown reason for using `scrbook` instead of `scrreprt`.

Comment: In this solution, the third page correctly shows 1.3 Third Section, because that section starts on top of the page. However, the second page (your page on the left) shows '1.2 second section' in the header, whereas that section only starts halfway in the page. How could I change the code so that the second page shows '1.1 First section'? Because that is the section that is on the top of that page.